# Simplest way to ask for a revenue

Tags: phrase-request

As per definition, "Revenue" is the amount of money that is brought into a company by its business activities. I have seen that most people (even some not well educated business person) get confused with this term.

Just want to understand, what would be the best question/explanation (in short) to ask for knowledge about a business's revenue?

Comment: Do you want to ask somebody to give your business money, or do you want to ask for knowledge about a business's revenue?

Comment: @ThePhoton To ask for knowledge about a business's revenue.

Comment: Have you looked up *revenue* in a dictionary? Were there example sentences? It's as simple as "What's the revenue of Company X?"

Comment: Also, *revenue* is normally a mass noun, not countable, so you would "ask for revenue", not "ask for **a** revenue".

Answer (score 1):

Since **revenue** is the *amount* you are looking for, you can simply ask

> How much is your **revenue** each year?
>   How much **revenue** do you generate each year?

Comment: Or even _What is your revenue?_ In principle this might be ambiguous (it could mean _what is the nature or source of your revenue?_) but in practice it is most likely to be asking for the amount.